# ExtJS how to dynamically create widgets and layouts from a string

Tags: string, templates, extjs, widget, render

Is there a possibility in ExtJS library to create layuots based on some string representation?

Consider I have a server call which fills a response with the following data - 
"**Ext.create('Ext.Button', {xtype: 'button', text: 'button form server'});**"  which is actually a valid javascript code to create a button ( being typed in source code editor it creates a button ).

Is there a way to get such a string response and to construct extjs's button based exactly on that string ?

For example: ajax's response.responseText equals to Ext.create('Ext.Button', {xtype: 'button', text: 'button form server'});. And what I demand is a component like Ext.someMagicStuff(response.responseText) which understands my passed string and creates a button.

Thank you very much for your time and any ideas !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not that complicated for defined types. Just return a valid config like

```
{xtype: 'button', text: 'button form server'}
```

as JSON and resolve the answer using

```
Ext.ComponentManager.create(Ext.decode(response.responseText));
```

The componentmanager will automatically lookup the xtype and return the created instance

Comment: Good advice, thanks! But, while trying to do that, there is a javaScript error occures - it tells - "unable to get substring property from a null or undetermined value". (ext-all-debug.js:5057 - tries to parse namespace)...

Comment: @user623417 I can't tell you anything without some code examples. Please post the server response along with a snipped where you process  it to get any further help.

Comment: Yeap) So, here they are - this is how I try to get and render server response: success: function(response){
var panel = Ext.getCmp('panelChoose');
panel.add(Ext.ComponentManager.create(response.responseText));
panel.doLayout();
}

Comment: this is the way response being created by the server: PrintWriter outWriter = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/html");
String outObj = "{xtype: 'button', text: 'button from server'}";
outWriter.println(outObj);
outWriter.close();

Comment: Following is the line in ext-all-debug.js file where NPE occures   if (name === from || name.substring(0, from.length) === from) ....                                                           where name is a namespace variable passed to the function - parseNamespace: function(namespace)

Comment: it works if I write: Ext.ComponentManager.create({xtype: 'button', text: 'hello'}, 'button');     But first parameter is not a string from the server - it is an Object. Is there a way to create such Object from string ( from server response ) ? Thank you!